# A question on Lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group ang let $\mathcal{g} = Lie(G)$ be the Lie algebra of $G$. If X and Y are left- invarient vector fields and  if X' and Y' are right-invariant vector fields such that
$$X_{e} = X'_{e} \quad , \quad Y_{e} = Y'_{e},$$
where $e$ is the identity element of $G$.
Then 
$$[X , Y]_{e} = - [X' , Y']_{e}.$$ I don't know how one can prove it.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Hint: prove that the inverse map $\iota: G \rightarrow G$ takes right-invariant vector fields to left-invariant vector fields, and its derivative at $e$ is $-Id$. Once you have done that, just observe that $\iota_*$ takes $X'$, $Y'$ to left-invariant vector fields whose initial conditions are opposite to those of $X$, $Y$, respectively. Now finish yourself ...

Comment: @Laz Is there any book or text that can help me to understand it in details?

Comment: @Laz Is there any book or text that can help me to understand it in details? you know, the one that can help me to learn more about Lie group and Lie transformation group on manifolds.

Comment: I suggest you Spivak's "A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry" Vol 1, or Frank Warner's "Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups". I am currently working on an answer, I will post it shortly ...

Comment: @Laz Thanks a lot. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I will assume that you know that given a Lie group $G$, the real vector space of all left-invariant vector fields with the Lie bracket form a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. The reason this is a Lie algebra is that a vector field is left-invariant iff it is $L_g$-related to itself $\forall g\in G$, where $L_g$ is the left translation by $g$. In exactly the same way, the real vector space of all right-invariant vector fields with the Lie bracket form a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}^r$.
This being said, I will make use of three lemmas:

$ \textbf{Lemma 1}:$ If $\mu:G\times G \rightarrow G$, $\iota: G \rightarrow G$ denote the multiplication and inverse maps, respectively, then $d\mu_{(e,e)}(x,y)=x+y$, $d\iota_e(x)=-x$.

$\textbf{Proof}:$ $d\mu_{(e,e)}(x,y)= d\mu_{(e,e)}(x,0)+d\mu_{(e,e)}(0,y)$. Now observe that given $\alpha:(-\epsilon, \epsilon)\rightarrow G$ with $\alpha(0)=e, \alpha'(0)=x$, the curve $\gamma:(-\epsilon, \epsilon)\rightarrow G\times G$ given by $\gamma(t)=(\alpha(t), e)$ satisfies $\gamma(0)=(e,e), \gamma'(0)=(x,0)$.
Thus, $d\mu_{(e,e)}(x,0)=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} (\mu\circ \gamma)=\alpha'(0)=x$.
For the second part, observe that $\mu\circ (Id_G\times\iota)(g)=\mu(g,g^{-1})=e$, $\forall g\in G$, i.e $\mu\circ (Id_G\times\iota)$ is constant $e$. Hence, 
$0=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} (\mu\circ (Id_G\times\iota)\circ\alpha)=
d\mu_{(e,e)}\circ d(Id_G\times\iota)_e (\alpha'(0))= d\mu_{(e,e)}(x,d\iota_e(x))=x+d\iota_e(x)$.

$\textbf{Lemma 2}:$ If $Z\in \mathfrak{g}^r$, $d\iota(Z)\in \mathfrak{g}$, where $d\iota$ denotes the pushforward by $\iota$ defined by $d\iota(Z)_g=(d\iota)_{g^{-1}}(Z_{g^{-1}})$.

$\textbf{Proof}:$ $d\iota(Z)_g=(d\iota)_{g^{-1}}(Z_{g^{-1}})=(d\iota)_{g^{-1}}(Z\circ R_{g^{-1}}(e))= (d\iota)_{g^{-1}}\circ (dR_{g^{-1}})_e(Z_e)=d(\iota\circ R_{g^{-1}})_e(Z_e)=d(L_g\circ\iota)_e(Z_e)= (dL_g)_e(-Z_e)=(dL_g)_e(d\iota(Z)_e).$

$\textbf{Lemma 3}:$ $d\iota: \mathfrak{g}^r\rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie algebra isomorphism.

$\textbf{Proof}$: The linearity is trivial. Lemma $\textbf{1}$ proves the injectivity, which concludes the isomorphism part.
Next, take $g\in G, f\in C^{\infty}(G)$, and $X', Y'\in \mathfrak{g}^r$ as you posted. Then:
 $[d\iota(X'), d\iota(X')](f)(g)=[d\iota(X'), d\iota(X')]_g(f)=d\iota(X')_g(d\iota(Y')(f))- d\iota(Y')_g(d\iota(X')(f))=(d\iota)_{g^{-1}}(X'_{g^{-1}})(d\iota(Y')(f))-(d\iota)_{g^{-1}}(Y'_{g^{-1}})(d\iota(X')(f))= X'_{g^{-1}}(d\iota(Y')(f)\circ \iota)-Y'_{g^{-1}}(d\iota(X')(f)\circ \iota).$
But $d\iota(Y')(f)\circ \iota (g)=d\iota(Y')(f) (g^{-1})=d\iota(Y')_{g^{-1}}(f)=(d\iota)_g(Y'_g)(f)=Y'_g(f\circ \iota)=Y'(f\circ \iota)(g).$
So, substituting $d\iota(Y')(f)\circ \iota=Y'(f\circ \iota)$ we get:
$[d\iota(X'), d\iota(X')](f)(g)= X'_{g^{-1}}(Y'(f\circ \iota))-Y'_{g^{-1}}(X'(f\circ \iota))=[X',Y']_{g^{-1}}(f\circ\iota)=(d\iota)_{g^{-1}}([X',Y']_{g^{-1}})(f)=d\iota([X',Y'])_g(f)= d\iota([X',Y'])(f)(g).$

Finally, with lemmas $\textbf{1}$ and $\textbf{2}$, it is clear that $d\iota(X')=-X, d\iota(Y')=-Y$. Now, with $\textbf{3}$ we have:
$d\iota([X',Y'])=[d\iota(X'),d\iota(Y')]=[-X,-Y]=[X,Y]$. So, again by $\textbf{1}$, $[X,Y]_e=-[X',Y']_e$.